# Join multiple mysql tables and group by

Tags: mysql, join, view, group-by

I have these tables:

**colors**

```
colorId colorName
1       Blu
2       Green
3       Yellow
4       Red
```

**colors_groups**

```
colorsGroupId  colorsGroupName
1              BG    
2              BY
3              RB
```

**colors_groups_ids**

```
colorsGroupId colorId  colorOrder
1             1        1
1             2        2
2             1        1
2             2        3
3             4        1
3             1        2
```

**books_covers**

```
bookId       colorsGroupId
1            1
1            2
2            2
```

Is it possible to have a view that gives results like this:

```
bookId       colorsGroupIds    colorsGroupName
1            1,2               BG (Blu/Green), BY (Blu/Yellow) 
2            2                 BY (Blu/Yellow)
```

I tried with two views both with group_by and the second one that joins the first one is very slow.
Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Edit.** I tried your view instead of mine, but the SELECT is very slow, and mysql explain the query like this:

```
id  select_type     table               type    possible_keys   key             key_len     ref             rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY         <derived2>          ALL     NULL            NULL            NULL        NULL            3320    
2   DERIVED         colors_groups       ALL     NULL            NULL            NULL        NULL            3320    Using filesort
2   DERIVED         colors_groups_ids   ref     colorsgroupid   colorsgroupid   3           colorsgroupid   1   
2   DERIVED         colors              eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY         2           colors.colorId  1       Using where
```

3220 is the number of color_groups record. Why is it using filesort and get every 3320 records two times?

This is the query:

```
SELECT
   groups.colorsGroupId, groups.colorsGroupName, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(groups_ids.colorId ORDER BY groups_ids.order ASC) AS colors_ids,
   GROUP_CONCAT(colors.colorName ORDER BY groups_ids.order ASC SEPARATOR "/") AS colors_names,
   CONCAT(groups.colorsGroupName, " (", GROUP_CONCAT(colors.colorName ORDER BY groups_ids.order ASC SEPARATOR "/"), ")") AS colors_names_complete,
   FROM colors_groups AS groups
   JOIN colors_groups_ids group_ids
   ON groups.colorsGroupId=group_ids.colorsGroupId
   JOIN colors
   ON group_ids.colorId=colors.colorId
   GROUP BY groups.colorsGroupId, groups.colorsGroupName
```

Comment: `I tried` Can we see that?

Comment: I edited the answer after I tried with your view

Comment: Tip: don't save it as a view - and you say 'instead of', but presently, you don't appear to have a query

Comment: Thank you. Does saving as a view change a lot?

Comment: Also, an EXPLAIN is very useful without also providing SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables

Comment: MySQL has very limited ability to access a view's underlying indexes (should they exist), rendering views almost useless in MySQL

Comment: Does this explain why as soon as I use a GROUP BY in a view everything slows down but not If I run the query "stand alone" (not in a view)?

Comment: No. It doesn't explain that. :-(

Comment: Thank you Strawberry. I "solved" with two views, I posted them as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that MySQL is fantastically bad a utilizing views, so to my mind, they serve no useful purpose.

Instead, consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS colors;

CREATE TABLE colors
(colorId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,colorName VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO colors VALUES
(11,'Blu'),
(12,'Green'),
(13,'Yellow'),
(14,'Red');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS color_groups;

CREATE TABLE color_groups
(colorsGroupId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,colorsGroupName CHAR(2) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO color_groups VALUES
(101,'BG'),
(102,'BY'),
(103,'RB');       

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS colors_groups_ids;

CREATE TABLE colors_groups_ids
(colorsGroupId INT NOT NULL
,colorId INT NOT NULL
,colorOrder INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(colorsGroupId,colorid)
);

INSERT INTO colors_groups_ids VALUES
(101,11,1),
(101,12,2),
(102,11,1),
(102,13,2), -- note: fixed the error in the original data set
(103,14,1),
(103,11,2);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book_covers;

CREATE TABLE book_covers
(bookId INT NOT NULL
,colorsGroupId INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(bookid,colorsgroupid)
);

INSERT INTO book_covers VALUES
(1001,101),
(1001,102),
(1002,102);

SELECT b.bookid
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT x.colorsgroupid ORDER BY x.colorsgroupid) colorsgroupids
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT x.colorsgroupname ORDER BY x.x.colorsgroupid) colorgroupname
  FROM book_covers b
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT g.colorsgroupid
            , CONCAT(g.colorsgroupname,' (',GROUP_CONCAT(c.colorname ORDER BY gc.colororder SEPARATOR '/' ),')') colorsgroupname 
         FROM color_groups g
         JOIN colors_groups_ids gc
           ON gc.colorsgroupid = g.colorsgroupid
         JOIN colors c
           ON c.colorid = gc.colorid
        GROUP
           BY g.colorsgroupid
            , g.colorsgroupname
     ) x
    ON x.colorsgroupid = b.colorsgroupid
  GROUP
     BY b.bookid;
+--------+----------------+--------------------------------+
| bookid | colorsgroupids | colorgroupname                 |
+--------+----------------+--------------------------------+
|   1001 | 101,102        | BG (Blu/Green),BY (Blu/Yellow) |
|   1002 | 102            | BY (Blu/Yellow)                |
+--------+----------------+--------------------------------+
```

Finally, as can be seen, this query uses CONCAT and GROUP_CONCAT. However, unless using some other aggregating functions (SUM/MAX/AVG), I think it's preferable to handle this kind of thing in application code.

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" with these views:

**colors_groups_view**

```
SELECT
colors_groups.colorsGroupId,
colors_groups.colorsGroupName,
colors_groups_ids.colorId,
colors_groups_ids.order,
colors.colorName 
FROM colors_groups 
LEFT JOIN colors_groups_ids ON colors_groups_ids.colorGroupId=colors_groups.colorGroupId
LEFT JOIN colors ON colors_groups.colorId=colors.colorId
```

This view give results like this:

```
colorsGroupId    colorsGroupName   colorId    order    colorName
1                BG                1          1        Blue
1                BG                2          2        Green
2                BY                1          1        Blue
2                BY                3          2        Yellow
```

And then:

**books_view**

```
SELECT 
books.bookId,
(
    SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        (
            SELECT 
            CONCAT(colors_groups_view.colorsGroupName, " (", GROUP_CONCAT(colors_groups_view.colorName ORDER BY colors_groups_view.order ASC SEPARATOR "/"), ")", "") AS booksGroupsNames 
            FROM colors_groups_view
            WHERE colors_groups_view.colorsGroupId=books_covers.colorsGroupId 
            GROUP BY colors_groups_view.colorsGroupId
        ) 
        SEPARATOR ", "
    )
    FROM books_covers 
    WHERE books_covers.bookId=books.bookId
    GROUP BY books_covers.bookId
) AS booksGroupsNames
FROM books
```

Since the first one doesn't GROUP_BY anything, it's very fast. I don't know if that can even be avoided and if everything can be done in only one query.